# Does order in which you wrap component with connect and withRouter matter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

Which HOC will wrap the other. Does the order of wrapping with multiple HOCs matter in react or not? I have created multiple HOCs **withSocket**, **withLoadingBar** etc etc. Should I be worry about deep ugly nesting, Will it make an impact on performance of component?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Does the order of wrapping with multiple HOCs matter in react or not?

The order in which you wrap the HOCs matters because of the props that are passed on from one HOC to its child component. Consider the following example

```
const mapStateToProps(state, props) {
   console.log(props.match);
   return {
      match: props.match
   }
}
```

**First case:**

```
withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

In this case since the `withRouter` wraps the `connect`, the props provided by `withRouter ie history, match etc` **will be** available in `mapStateToProps` used by connect.

Think of an HOC like

```
const MyComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

where `withRouter` could be implement like

```
const withRouter = (Comp) => {
    return class Something extends React.Component {
      render() {
         return <Comp match={this.context.router.match} />
      }
    }
    ..
}
```

and so in this case, the `Comp` i.e `MyComponent` which is wrapped with `withRouter` receives the match props, which in the above case is the component being wrapped by `connect`

**Second case:**

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(App));
```

In this case since the connect wraps the withRouter, the props provided by `withRouter` ie `history, match etc` **will not be** available in `mapStateToProps` used by `connect` if they are not provided by the parent.

> Should I be worry about deep ugly nesting?

you should only worry about it if the props provided by one HOC is being used by another. Say if you use passed down props from HOC directly inside the base component, you won't need to worry about the order

> Will it make an impact on performance of component?

The order of using HOC doesn't affect a components performance

Check the below codesandbox for an example

[image: Edit Simple state wrapper]

Comment: I think that it is exactly the other way round. You need to apply `withRouter` first to have the `match` object in the `ownProps` in `mapStateToProps`. Nested functions are called from the inner to the outer function. So your first case will not work.

Comment: @trixn, yes, that is what I wrote in my answer. Isn't it clear??

Comment: No you wrote that in your first case, `match` will be available in `mapStateToProps` but it will not since you apply `withRouter()` **after** `connect()` has already been called.

Comment: @trixn, no you are wrong about it, the wrapper doesn't get the props, the wrapped component does

Comment: @trixn, added a demo for the explanation

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamKhatri for such a detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

React is all about composition and in the majority of cases it shouldn't be a performance problem at all. Don't worry about it until you actually perceive a performance issue. Nesting HOC's is also fine. The only thing you need to take into consideration is when one of the HOC's consumes props injected by another HOC. This is e.g. the case when you need `react-router` url params in your `mapStateToProps` to select an object by `id`. Then you need to apply first the `connect()` HOC and only then the `withRouter()` HOC to access the `match` object in the `ownProps` of the wrapped component.