# You should not use Route outside a Router after use of withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have to use this.props.history.push('/...') in a nested component so I added **withRouter()** to navigate without history problems using react-router-dom.

But since I have added withRouter, I have **You should not use Route outside a Router** error.
I have read posts about this error but I can't understand what is wrong with my code.

Root.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
...
const Root = ({ store }) => (
          <Router>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_test_XXXXXXXXX">
                  <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
                      <Route path="/comp1" component={Comp1} />
                      <Route path="/comp2" component={Comp2} />
                      <Route path="/store" component={MyStoreCheckout} />
                      <Route component={Notfound} />
                  </Switch>
                </StripeProvider>
             </Provider>
          </Router>
)
Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
export default withRouter(Root)
```

and index.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import myReducer from './redux/Reducers/myReducer'
import Root from './Root'
import Store from './redux/Store/store'

render(<Root store={Store} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I use withRouter to be able to call this.props.history(...) in CheckoutForm
MyStoreCheckout.js:

```
class MyStoreCheckout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Elements>
        <InjectedCheckoutForm />
      </Elements>
    );
  }
}
export default MyStoreCheckout;
```

CheckoutForm.js:

```
class CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    fetch(getRequest)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(...)
        .then(() => this.goToSuccessPage())
  }

  goToSuccessPage(){
    this.props.history.push('/') ; //----- error is here if I have no withRouter

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <DetailsSection/>
        <CardSection />
        <button>Confirm order</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

Comment: yeah, `withRouter` can only be used in a component that is nested within `<Router>` - like, in your code, `StripeProvider`, `App`, `Comp1`, `Comp2`, `NotFound`

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher I edited my question. How can I use withRouter then, to be able to reach a page in CheckoutForm  ?

Comment: Just do `import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'` at the top of your `CheckoutForm` file, then wrap `injectStripe(CheckoutForm)` with it like this: `withRouter(injectStripe(CheckoutForm))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment... Just import `withRouter` at the top of your `CheckoutForm` file, then wrap the export with it, at the bottom. Like this:

CheckoutForm.js:

```
import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

class CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
  // ... your class code ...
}

export default withRouter(injectStripe(CheckoutForm));
```

If your `injectStripe` HOC doesn't pass all of the props from `withRouter` down to `CheckoutForm`, you can try doing `export default injectStripe(withRouter(CheckoutForm));` instead, but [order shouldn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384270/does-order-in-which-you-wrap-component-with-connect-and-withrouter-matter) (if set up correctly)